# Why SmartGWT does not have Paginated Grid?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Curious to know why `SmartGWT` does not have Paginated Grid?

It is must have feature for all enterprise applications.
I found Serendipity sample but it is not working in latest version of `SmartGWT`.
Can I expect pagination enabled Grid in future ?

Comment: More a question for the Smartgwt team on the forum

Answer (score 2):

Currently SmartGWT does not support  paginated grid, but there are several ways how this can be solved. First, you can use live grid, which allows you to dynamically load content. Second, you can write your own pagination, placing the buttons below the table. When you click on them you will receive new portions of the content. I used the second way and the implementation was pretty simple.
Hope, these solutions will help you

Comment: I was wondering why they haven't provided this support. I have to go by the second solution as you suggested which I have already considered in my plan. It seems bit of pain to do this boiler plate code isn't it? Hope to have paginated grid in SmartGWT soon.

Comment: Maybe this topic on SmartGWT forum  will be useful for you: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3103&highlight=pagination

Comment: Link seems unresponsive.