# How to apply Paging in smartgwt Listgrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I have to show around more than 10,000 records in a **listgrid**. My code is working fine but I am facing performance issue it takes too much time for it.
I want to apply pagination in **Listgrid**, so I can increase my **listgrid** performance. I find the following method documentation mentioned about paging but I was not able to apply it. Can any one please explain how can I use this method??

```
protected void transformResponse(DSResponse response,
                                 DSRequest request, Object data)
```

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#transformResponse%28com.smartgwt.client.data.DSResponse,%20com.smartgwt.client.data.DSRequest,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: It is kind of hard to answer without knowing how you populate your listgrid.  In `DSRequest`, methods 'setStartRow()` and 'setEndRow()` are used to fetch the appropriate records.  In `DSResponse`, you find the same methods and also 'setTotalRows()` to tell the listgrid which part of the results you fetched.  Using these methods depends on how you fetch your data for the listgrid.

Comment: @EricC.I set the list in the datasource,then set the datasource in the Listgrid. datasource.setdata(list)   then set the listgrid.setdatasource(datasource) ; I have made all 10,000 records then i am setting in the listgrid .I want that as i make the some records 100 or 200 then i show it in the listgrid and in background the records are generating.

Comment: Depends on how your server fetch is built but you may just have to use `listgrid.setDataFetchMode(FetchMode.PAGED)` and `listgrid.setDataPageSize(100);`

Comment: @Dhruva, I recommend going through this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468486/support-of-pagination-in-smartgwt-for-listgrid) once. & also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799090/why-smartgwt-does-not-have-paginated-grid

Comment: @EricC. I have already done this it helps to load the object as we scrolldown the listgrid but my need is pagination as the requirement  told.
dataSource.setResultBatchSize(50);    grid.setDataFetchMode(FetchMode.PAGED);   grid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.VERTICAL);
grid.setShowAllRecords(false);
grid.setDataPageSize(50);
grid.setAutoFetchData(Boolean.TRUE);
Thanks for ur suggestions

Comment: Ah, what you call pagination is management of data with tabs (ex: tab1 contains 50rows then tab2 another 50 and so on...).  This is not implemented in smartgwt but take a look at @RAS links.

Answer (score -1):

By using pagination for listgrid you manually prepare pagination bar and put some controls onclick that controls the listgrid load the data. I am trying it's working and we are sure we increase grid performance.